# Ubuntu tty1 - 6 blank screen

Tags: ati, graphics, virtual-terminal

I cannot access ubuntu console by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1 - F6.
It only shows blank screen (black).
I don't know since when, just found out recently.
I suspect that fglrx driver is the problem (ATI Radeon).

I haven't tried to remove the fglrx driver (because I don't know how and I need it for graphic acceleration).

Any ide how to fix this?